# Get IMEI via ADB only for old Huawei models

Tags: android, adb, huawei-mobile-services

I need a bit of assistance. I have a Huawei g6-l11 (with Android 4.3) from which I am trying to extract the IMEI via ADB. I know that this device is ancient, but this is one of my tasks. So far I had tried everything I could find on the internet, like:

1) `adb shell getprop | grep "<IMEI>"`

2) `adb shell service call iphonesubinfo N | grep "<IMEI>"` - Where N is a number between 1 and 50

3) `adb shell settings get secure android_id`

4) `adb shell content query --uri content://settings/secure | grep "<IMEI>"`

5) `adb shell content query --uri content://settings/system | grep "<IMEI>"`

6) `adb shell content query --uri content://settings/global | grep "<IMEI>"`

7) `adb shell dumpsys | grep "<IMEI>"`

So I had made an Android app and run this piece of code on the smartphone:

```
val tm = this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
Log.d("Emy_","The IMEI is ${tm.deviceId}")
```

That worked fine but it is an Android app when I need to do the same thing but only via ADB.

Also, I had found a [fastboot command](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/huawei/huawei-p10/faq/read-info-fastboot/) that would help me (like: `fastboot oem get-psid`). But the problem is that I need to reboot the phone into fast boot mode. Which is taking too long.

My questions are:

1) why is it different for Huawei models with the OS version below Marshmallow to extract the IMEI?

2) how could I replicate the function call done by the Java code to be done with the ADB in the terminal? Or in other words, what other commands would you recommend to me to try to extract the IMEI?

Comment: did you try `adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo` on devices below android 5 without the `service call` commands. I've tested on emulator running android 4.3

Comment: Yes, I had tried that command and enumerated it at point 7. And because you had provided a piece of code, here is the output of the command.                                                 command: "C:\Users\gresa>adb.exe shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo"
, output: "Phone:  Subscriber Info:
  Phone Type = GSM"

Comment: Ok, on the 4.3 android emulator the output was `Phone Subscriber Info: Phone Type = GSM Device ID = 358240051111110`. So after the `Phone Type = GSM` it also displayed the Device ID

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I had executed that command on the real device. And the output is different. Thanks, I will keep digging. But if you have any other suggestions, I am only years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could display it on screen:

```
adb am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:*%2306%23
```

Comment: Hey, you are not entirely wrong.  But your answer is not complete. And yes, I could execute your command and on the phone screen, the IMEI will be displayed. And by running the command "adb shell uiautomator dump" I will make an XML capture of the screen. And in this XML to search for a pattern to extract return back only the IMEI.

Comment: @GreşanuEmanuel-Vasile this sounds quite complicated for reading out that string... but it might be one of those cases, where "while it works" is good enough, since there don't seem to be much alternatives. Thanks for the bounty and for completing the solution approach... with `adb wait-for-device`, one could even optimize that for batch-processing many devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you just searching to know the IMEI, You can try this code : `*#06#`
Or you can try this : `adb shell
service call iphonesubinfo 1 | toybox cut -d "'" -f2 | toybox grep -Eo '[0-9]' | toybox xargs | toybox sed 's/\ //g'`
 hop that  help you !

Comment: The software that I am building needs to extract the IMEI, so the user shouldn't do anything. Also, the problem with the piece of code you had provided is returning nothing.  "adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 1" is telling me that I don't have permissions. Also, I had mentioned this line us "not working", at point 2.

Comment: I think *%2306%23 == *#06#